# Is it possible to edit doc files with Python?

Tags: python, ms-word

I have a set of .doc files which I want to perform some simple changes to (e.g. set the font of all the text in each file to be arial).

I don't want to do all the operations manually. I thought I'll try to automate it with a Python script. Is it a complicated task? How is it done?

I use Python 3.

Comment: Windows or OS X? On OS X, use Applescript or Automator.

Comment: Thanks, but I'm using Windows. Is there an Applescript/Automator equivalent for Windows?

Comment: Hello, did anyone find a way to manipulate older versions of doc files? (like word 97 or older)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The [Python docx module](https://github.com/mikemaccana/python-docx) should be helpful.

(2nd time this question was asked today!)

Comment: The docx mod does not support .doc.