# Is it possible to edit MS word doc files with Python?

Tags: python

I need to create a lot of old .doc files (MS word 97) and I'm wondering if there is any way to do in Python 3. I've been researching around but all I can find are libraries for the newer .docx files or playing with the OpenOffice API.

The output files would be just a .doc file with specific formatting and some tables with text inside the cells. No images or fancy stuff needed, but I hesitate on installing external programs like OpenOffice because this script will need to run on a few different computers. So I'm wondering if there is just a library that I can import.

I accept suggestions for other programming languages as well, but Python would be perfect.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Is it possible to edit doc files with Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226824/is-it-possible-to-edit-doc-files-with-python)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [html to .doc converter in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226095/html-to-doc-converter-in-python)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

yes, try http://python-docx.readthedocs.io/en/latest/

to install:

pip install python-docx

Comment: Isn't that just for .docx files? The documentation says it won't work with files older than 2007.

Comment: It is just for .docx files