# Replacing a phrase in a `.doc` file with python

Tags: python, linux, ms-word, python-docx, .doc

I have a `.doc` file that contains text, I need to replace a particular phrase with another one in this document.

I tried using `python-docx` but it doesn't support the `.doc` format. I also tried using the normal string replace functionality but it's corrupting the doc file

```
with open("input.doc") as r:
   text = r.read().replace("old text", "new text")
with open("output.doc", "w") as w:
   w.write(text)
```

I can't change the extension of the file and I want to do it in python.

Comment: There are some possible pointers here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36001482/read-doc-file-with-python - However, you also want to save, so it's not a duplicate.

Comment: There is also https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4226824/is-it-possible-to-edit-doc-files-with-python, but the question is not correctly answered there, too.

Comment: @Hans they all are about reading the text from the .doc file but i need to edit it and save it in the same format without corrupting it.

Answer (score 0):

I think you must open the files in binary mode:

```
open("input.doc", "rb")
```

and

```
open("output.doc", "wb")
```

You must change the "replace" method to adequate it to binary mode.